# Color MObject with inner arc

Tags: manim

I am using manim community where I created an MObject by using Line and ArcBetweenPoints.
When I try to fill the MObject, the object is colored between by the start and end point of the larger arc. Is there a way to color this MObject correctly?

Please take a look at the code below to visualize the problem. By uncommenting the line with 'set_fill' you see how the object is filled incorrectly.

```
%%manim -qm -v WARNING MobjectExample
    g1 = [-1.5, 0, 0]
    g2 = [0, -1.5, 0]
    g3 = [1.5, 0, 0]
    g7 = [0.5, 0, 0]
    g8 = [0, -0.5, 0]
    g9 = [-0.5, 0, 0]
    
    class MobjectExample(Scene):
        def construct(self):
            g = ArcBetweenPoints(start=g1, end=g2, stroke_color=BLUE) \
                .append_points(ArcBetweenPoints(start=g2, end=g3).points) \
                .append_points(ArcBetweenPoints(start=g8, end=g7).points) \
                .append_points(ArcBetweenPoints(start=g9, end=g8).points)\
                .append_points(Line(g1, g9).points)\
                .append_points(Line(g3, g7).points)
            # Please uncomment the next line to color the object
            # g.set_fill(BLUE, opacity=1)
            self.play(Create(g))
            self.wait(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `append_points` has a weird effect on the mobject, in the sense that not one continuous path is drawn, but multiple ones that form some sort of group. You can fix this by using `append_vectorized_mobject` instead, which takes care of correctly merging different paths together. And: when you concatenate mobject points like that you have to make sure that the points actually describe a continuous path; the endpoint of the n-th subpath has to be the start point of the (n+1)-th.

Try this:

```py
class MobjectExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        g = ArcBetweenPoints(start=g1, end=g2, stroke_color=BLUE)
        g.append_vectorized_mobject(ArcBetweenPoints(start=g2, end=g3))
        g.append_vectorized_mobject(Line(g3, g7))
        g.append_vectorized_mobject(ArcBetweenPoints(start=g7, end=g8, angle=-TAU/4))
        g.append_vectorized_mobject(ArcBetweenPoints(start=g8, end=g9, angle=-TAU/4))
        g.append_vectorized_mobject(Line(g9, g1))
        g.set_fill(BLUE, opacity=1)
        self.play(Create(g))
        self.wait(2)
```